# How can I execute a Vim command followed by external commands execution?

Tags: vim

The command looks like this

```
autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer> mark s | $r ! ruby % | sed 's/^/\#=> /' | 's
```

It will append the output and move cursor to the original position, before appending.

This is the error I got:

```
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Auto commands for "<buffer=1>":
E485: Can't read file /var/folders/fw/045tt2q10zv1qkbfbw73y8c80000gn/T/vCDqw9b/7
```

If remove `| 's` at the end of line, it works fine, but no returning to the marked `s` position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The `:read ! ...` command cannot be concatenated with other Vim commands; it treats *all* following text as the command to execute. This causes the shell error. See `:help :bar`. You can fix this by wrapping with `:execute`.
2. `'s` is a *normal mode* command; to use it in a command-line, you need to prefix the `:normal` Ex command.

```
autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer> mark s | execute "$r ! ruby % | sed 's/^/\#=> /' " | normal! 's
```